# Does 100x writing 1 letter to a text file significantly wear down a hard drive / ssd more, than writing 1x 100 letters at once?

Tags: python, performance, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

Basically I'm writing hundreds of times per minute to a log file, I wonder if it makes a significant difference to the longevity of a hdd / ssd whether I write every change directly to the log file, or if I should just temporarily save the changes in ram and dump them once a minute to the log?

Not sure if relevant, but I'm using python's:

`with open('log.txt', 'a') as log: log.write('a')`
command

Comment: The behavior under the curtains likely does not change much unless you `flush=True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't make any significant difference. Python uses buffered output when writing the file, and the OS has file buffers in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Usually modern hardware prevents excessive writes to disk by using [a cache](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/6867/disk-cache).
This solves the hardware degradation problem, however the performance is affected significantly. You'll spend a lot less CPU if you write these log entries in blocks.

Comment: Is the performance affected for the better or for the worse by a cache?

Comment: Performance is **always** better with cache. It uses space and could cause inconsistencies, but performance will never decrease with it.

Comment: Because you wrote "however", it sounded like using a cache was a drawback.

Comment: I meant performance degradation caused by writing 100x on the same file. The cache prevents it from being worse, but even with cache doing 100 writes per minute is bad for performance

Answer (score 0):

In general, the dominant factor in the longevity of a HDD/SSD is the number of writes to sectors/cells. This is basically **how many bytes are written**. It is unlikely that how users write, with or without buffering, will have a significant impact on its lifespan.